# Why is getExternalStoragePublicDirectory working in all Android versions up to 14?

Tags: android, permissions, storage

I've created a simple app which has a functionality that writes a txt (or an xlsx) file to the Downloads directory. It has no interest in shared folders beyond that.

I have struggled with the `ActivityResultLauncher` mechanism, where you request run-time permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. See this link:

- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

It so happens this **no longer works** after Android 13 (more granular permissions are required).

Lo and behold, it turns out the following, simple piece of code [go to message end] manages to write those files to the Downloads folder in all Android versions (emulated) without requiring any permissions.

For the record, the Manifest still contains this line, but even without it files are still successfully saved:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

What am I missing here? Why is this working so well? I've read somewhere `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is deprecated (not marked as so by the IDE, though).

```
public void saveFile(String fileName, byte[] fileBytes) {
    final File downloadsFolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    if (Objects.isNull(downloadsFolder)) {
        Log.e(LOG_PREFIX, "The downloads folder was null");
        toaster.show(R.string.collections_fragment_lack_permission_to_write_file);
        return;
    }

    if (!downloadsFolder.exists()) {
        if (!downloadsFolder.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(LOG_PREFIX, "The downloads folder does not exist, and an attempt to create it failed");
            toaster.show(R.string.collections_fragment_lack_permission_to_write_file);
            return;
        }
    }

    final File file = new File(downloadsFolder, fileName);
    try {
        final var fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(fileBytes);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_PREFIX, "Something went wrong while attempting to write to the downloads folder");
        toaster.show(R.string.collections_fragment_lack_permission_to_write_file);
    }

    sendFileExportedNotification(fileName);
}
```

Comment: You have to request that write permission at runtime for all Android versions up to twelve. We dont believe you can do without.

Answer (score 1):

From my practice, it's still possible to access public downloads directory, even on Android 14, but only for your app files. If you for example try to override another app file you will get exception. That's in line with the scoped storage idea.

Unfortunately, the docs doesn't mention it.